# App Engine memcache speed "dict" vs "Class Object"

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have page handler with 95% traffic, it fetches model from DB using its key and then uses fields in the fetched model to fill a django template.

I want to memcache the fetched model so as to avoid DB reads.  Not all fields of the model are used in template so i want to cache it with just the required feilds so as to improve cache utilization and fit more such models in cache.

So i want to convert the Model in a dictionary or 'class boject' with only the fields required in template.

**Memcache uses pickle to serialize values, so for serialization purpose which will be faster   dictionary or 'class object'??**

Comment: you mean 'class object'?

Comment: @ShayErlichmen Fixing the typo would have been quicker than complaining about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to measure but for all intended purposes the results should be that its about the same speed.
If any method tend to be faster I don't really think its going to impact you overall performance that much.
Your main latency will be the RPC call to the memache which might be two factor slower then the slowest serialization.

Answer (score 2):

Neither! Instead, cache the entity Protocol Buffer, as [described here](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Efficient-model-memcaching).

You might want to consider switching to [NDB](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/), which has built in support for memcaching model instances.

Comment: HI Nick,
Thanks a lot, not only for this reply but also for your great blog,

Answer (score 1):

You should consider defining [`__getstate__` / `__setstate__`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) methods on your model class so that you can select just the properties on your model that you want to cache, and to simplify the reification process; your unpickled data arrives as an actual instance of the model instead of  a stand in you'll have to somehow convert in another way.

Comment: Thanks for the clue, tanks a lot  TokenMacGuy